# cakePHP User Edit creates empty user

Tags: php, cakephp

I currently have a probem with cakePHP:
If I open /users/edit/4 for example, a new empty user entry is created in the users database.

My UsersController:

```
  public function edit($id = null) {
      if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->User->find('first', $options);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

With kind regards,

Battlestr1k3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add the `$id`

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $this->request->data['User']['id'] = $id;
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->User->find('first', $options);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to assignto $userData. You can directly modify $this->request->data.

Comment: yes, you are right. I just wrote it that way to be easier to see.

Comment: IMO a single line `$this->request->data['User']['id'] = $id` is easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
public function edit($id = null) {
  if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
}
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
} else {
    $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->request->data = $this->User->find('first', $options);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your fast answers, they both worked.
I was confused, because the code got even called when I made a GET-Request with a browser, but the problem was a javascript function which made a POST-Request in the background.

With kind regards,

Battlestr1k3